# How to retrieve data from JSON in Javascript

Tags: javascript, nativescript

I am new to JavaSript and NativeScript. I am able to get a JSON string from an API call. I am trying to parse through JSON.parse it but unfortunately I am not getting anything.Can anyone help?

```
exports.signIn = async function() {

await fetchModule.fetch(apiurl,{
    method:"POST",
    body:JSON.stringify({"username":username ,"password":password}),
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      } 
}).then(function(response){
    var result = JSON.parse(response)
    alert(result.username)
})
```

}

Comment: Too less information. Please post the data sample

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for tips on asking questions.

Comment: if you're passed a json object, why do you need to parse it? did you include `.map(res => res.json())` on the http request?

Comment: did you check what you are getting in "response"

Comment: Yes. I am getting a JSON object

Comment: if "response" is already a JSON object then you are trying to use JSON.parse on it.  Using JSON.parse on an object will give you "uncaught syntax error" with explanation unexpected token. check you developer console for the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this

```
exports.signIn = async function() {

await fetchModule.fetch(apiurl,{
    method:"POST",
    body:JSON.stringify({"username":username ,"password":password}),
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      } 
}).then(function(response){
    alert(response.username)
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is working!!